# Mysql and Sessions , PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session

I currently have a website that users log in and uses sessions.

The currently login and use the " users " table and it directs them to the appropriate page. I have another table that stores other details about the user.

I wish to display information to them from this other table, but they are controlled by their username in a session, Can I link the second table?

Comment: you should have some sort of user_id column in your info table to make the relation

Comment: You should have column(mostly primary key or unique index) in your tables which can be used to JOIN them. Read more about SQL JOINs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a column on your table to set who is allowed to view that link by adding a user type definition to your table of users.

user_privilege = set(admin, customer, stupid)

Then check user privileges